# How do I change an ImageButton to its selected state in an android widget?

Tags: android, widget, imagebutton

Why can't I make the code below work?

```
widgetBtn.setSelected(true);
```

or

```
views.setBoolean(R.id.widgetBtn, "setSelected", true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nopressed"/>

</selector>
```

in ur drawable.